# Can I filter a List of List in R by class/type?

Tags: r, list

I'm working with a list that has different types of objects and that's preventing me from using rbind. I just need to filter out the lines with Type/Class function. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your data. You can share data using the dput() function. Also, please be more clear about your overall problem. Is you just have a list with eight objects simply select the list items you need and drop the others e.g. `new_list <- list[c(2,3,4,5,6,8)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to get the class of each element and filter from there:

```
example_list <- list("df" = iris, "vector" = letters, "number" = 5, "fun" = mean)
example_list[sapply(example_list, class) != "function"]
```

Comment: Or use `Filter()` to do it in one step: `Filter(function(x) class(x)!="function", example_list)`

Comment: I wouldn't use `class` and the `==`, since the `class` attribute might be a vector with length > 1. Much better to use `inherits`, like `sapply(example_list,inherits,"function")`. To be noticed that if an element has a `class` attribute with length 2 or more, `sapply` won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `purr`'s `keep`/`discard` :

```
library(purrr)

#1)
result <- keep(news1432, ~!inherits(.x, 'function'))

#2)
result <- discard(news1432, inherits, 'function')
```

Thanks to @nicola for suggestion of using `inherits`.

Comment: See my comment on the other answer regarding the preferrable usage of `inherits`.